# How to target a specific event type in a system workflow message

Tags: civievent, civimail, system-workflow-messages

We'd like to separate the receipt for signing up for events by the event type - an email for one specific type and another one for all the other events. However, I haven't figured out how to specifically target it yet.

Right now we have something that looks like this:

```
{if $event.confirm_email_text AND (not $isOnWaitlist AND not $isRequireApproval)}

     some text...

{else}

     some more text

     {$event.confirm_email_text|htmlize}

{/if}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `event_type_id` token inside the event templates. Something like -

```
{if $event.event_type_id == <id of the event type>}

  text for the specific event type

{else} 

  common text for all other events

{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I was having a hard time finding the right token and it's not in the list of easy to access tokens.